# julia: Are nested functions slower?

Tags: julia, nested-function

When I write a code, and I can see repeat parts in a function but aren't used in the other functions.

So, I want to make repeat part to function.

But are nested functions slower? I couldn't find this in Performance tip in julia docs.

Comment: Why not write a benchmark and test it?

Comment: In general: 1) function calls in Julia are fast, 2) small functions will be inlined by the compiler. The detailed answer to your question depends on the exact implementation you have, so in order to precisely answer the question we would need the code you have.

Comment: @NicoHaase Of course, I wrote a benchmark code, but I don't know general benchmark method and I want know general case

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has been generally answered by Bogumil in the comment. Just to realize that inlining works you can do this small experiment. Define the following `f` and `g` functions.

```
f(x) = x*x

function g(a,b)
  a+f(b)
end
```

Now let's see what compiler does with them:

```
julia> @code_typed g(3,4)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Base.mul_int(b, b)::Int64
│   %2 = Base.add_int(a, %1)::Int64
└──      return %2
) => Int64
```

You can see that the call to the function `f` has been inlined.

Generally small functions will be inlined, the larger ones can be decorated with the `@inline` macro to suggest the compiler in-lining (note that this is only a hint). Since the cost of calling a function is small when it has more than just a few lines of code, calling it does not affect performance in a significant way.

Last but not least doing your own benchmark with `BenchmarkTools` seems always like a good idea :-)